# WebSphere MQ Object Naming Conventions

Tags: ibm-mq

What are the recommended guidelines for WebSphere MQ naming conventions for queue managers, queues (local, remote, transmit, dead letter queues...), channels etc. I found one at IBM's [developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0807_hsieh/0807_hsieh.html) but looking to see if there is anything else comprehensive out there. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like a good topic for a new *[Mission:Messaging](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/websphere/libraryview.jsp?site_id=1&contentarea_by=WebSphere&sort_by=Date&sort_order=2&start=1&end=11&topic_by=&product_by=&type_by=All%20Types&show_abstract=true&search_by=Mission:Messaging:)* column but I'll write up the condensed version here.  I'll preface my answer by noting that many of my recommendations are contrary to those you might find elsewhere. In some cases this is because the way MQ is commonly used have changed over the years.  In other cases it is because the conventional wisdom never worked well to begin with. (Cluster channels named `TO.QMGR` for example.) In all cases, I prefer conventions which apply to the broadest number of situations. That means it is usually possible to find exceptions to these rules for specific cases but they are broadly applicable nonetheless.

**Some general rules**
The following apply to all object types.

*Use the dot character `.` as a separator.*
Authorization rules parse names using dot characters as separators.  For example, the queue name `MY.EXAMPLE.QUEUE.NAME` would match rules like `MY.*.*.*` or `MY.**` but not `MY.*` because the dots signify name node separator characters.  Do yourself a favor and use dots rather than underscores as your naming node separators consistently.

*Use machine-parsable names.*
When you have 5 queue managers and a few hundred objects, you can easily get by doing all your management manually with WMQ Explorer or runmqsc.  However, there comes a point where consistency, reliability, repeatability and efficiency demand that you script up some of your routine operations or employ instrumentation to respond to network events. More than anything else this means eliminating ambiguity in names.

For example, if you create a naming convention that channel names must look like `SRCQMGR.DESTQMGR` then it is possible for a script to read a `RCVR` or `SDR` channel name and derive the names of the two queue managers it connects.  However, what does the script do with a channel name like `GA.PAYROLL.OPS`?  Is it the `GA.PAYROLL` queue manager connecting to the `OPS` queue manager?  Or is it the `GA` queue manager connecting to the `PAYROLL.OPS` queue manager? A human might be able to tell instantly based on context but scripts are notorious for doing what you tell them rather than what you intended. Similar situations arise when queue names have position-dependent qualifiers at both the beginning and the end of the name and a variable number of nodes.

*Stick with UPPERCASE names.*
This is for compatibility across all platforms, and in particular z/OS.  Although it is true that more z/OS shops are using mixed case, it is also true that there are still a lot of systems out there that only accept UPPERCASE names.  While it is easy to say "this doesn't apply to me" I have seen many cases where somebody had problems interfacing to a new business partner because of incompatible names.  After all, the ability to interface to just about any platform out there is one of the main reasons for using WMQ in the first place.

*Don't include attributes of the object in the name*
In an SOA world, queues and topics are different types of destination and often are interchangeable.  Something putting messages to what it thinks is a queue doesn't necessarily know (or care!) if they are actually going to a queue or a topic.  A queue that has an application listening on it for messages may be fed by an administrative subscription that is actually roping in publications from one or more topics.

What we really care about is the nature of the messages - what function do they perform - not whether we are connecting to a local queue or an alias queue.  So adding qualifiers like `.QA`, `.QL`, `.TPC` (for topic) and so forth doesn't make sense.  Similarly, adding `.RCVR` onto a channel name sucks up 5 useful characters that could have been better used describing the QMgr name.  Worse, these practices bake the topology into the object names, making the system both less flexible and more brittle.

**Channel names**

*Point-to-Point Channel names*
Use names like `SRCQMGR.DESTQMGR` for `RCVR`, `RQSTR`, `SDR`, and `SVR` channels. This is biased toward languages that read left-to-right because the intention is to describe the data flow *from* a QMgr *to* another QMgr

*Cluster channels*
Use names like `CLUSNAME.QMNAME`.  The old wisdom said to use names like `TO.QMNAME` but if you ever implement overlapping clusters this causes the same channel to be used for multiple clusters.  That's bad because you can then never perform maintenance on one cluster without impacting the other.  Using `CLUSNAME.QMNAME` insures that every QMgr has a dedicated `CLUSRCVR` channel for each cluster in which it participates.

*Client Channels*
The exception to the "don't include attributes of the object in the name" is arguably the `SVRCONN` channel.  This is because channels are very much tied to the physical rather than the logical layer of the network.  So putting the QMgr name in a SVRCONN channel name is generally OK.  I don't object too strongly if people want to add `.SVRCONN` at the end, either.

The thing to remember about client channels is that if you use a Client Channel Definition Table (CCDT) then the unique index into that table is the channel name.  That means you cannot have the same channel name on multiple QMgrs and still use a CCDT.  Since the CCDT is one way to configure the SSL/TLS channel details, this is often not appreciated to its fullest until the "let's finally secure WMQ" project comes along.  By using unique channel names for `SVRCONN` channels from the start, you can future-proof the network.  Usually these names look like `APP.QMNAME` or to make it obvious you aren't dealing with a cluster or point-to-point channel, `APP.QMNAME.SVRCONN` or similar.

**Queue manager names**

*No dots in QMgr names*
One implication of the previous rules is that cluster and queue manager names must contain only one node and therefore should never contain a `.` character.  This is because channel names are typically derived from the cluster and/or QMgr names.  So in the example above, a `RCVR` channel name like `GA_PAYROLL.OPS` would tell both humans and scripts that the channel in question connects a QMgr named `GA_PAYROLL` to a QMgr named `OPS`.

*Names of 9 chars or less*
Channel names can be only 20 characters.  Subtract one for the dot separator, divide by two and round down gets you to 9 characters max for queue managers.  If there's a possibility that you may set up different channels for classes of service (for large vs small messages, for example, then drop back to 8 chars or less for QMgr names.  This leads to `QM1.QM2.A`, `QM1.QM2.B`, etc.

*QMgr names reflect the physical layer*
In a service-oriented world, we really care about destination names like queues and topics.  We care much less about queue manager names because these are just life support for queues and topics.  Client apps don't care so much about *which* QMgr the connect to, so long as they can send requests and receive replies.  WMQ very conveniently fills in the reply-to QMgr name on outbound requests so it is rare that an application needs to know about it.

On the other hand, the administrators need to know about the QMgr name.  In the early days it was common to name QMgrs for the host server.  Later it became the fashion to name them for the applications they hosted. Now in the SOA world, messaging is infrastructure and usually not associated with any single application so the pendulum has swung back. Give the QMgr a unique name that is meaningful to an administrator.

*Never reuse QMgr names!*
It is unfortunately very common to "move" a QMgr from one place to another or to have a primary and disaster recovery QMgr with the same name.  This practice usually means some part of the application is dependent on the QMgr name and therefore it is "easier" to reuse the name.  IBM introduced the `QMID` as a way to address some of the problems introduced by reusing QMgr names.  The typical use case is that a node gets rebuilt and the QMgr once there is also rebuilt from scratch.  The cluster knows it is a new QMgr because the `QMID` has changed, but the name used for routing and other operations remains the same.

Although this helped in that limited use case, it doesn't address the issues when both QMgrs with the same name are online at the same time.  Nor does it address the problem that a reputable Certificate Authority won't issue multiple certs with the same Distinguished Name which forces reuse of the same certificate for multiple QMgrs.

Remember that QMgrs are just life support for queues and topics and ideally will be anonymous to the applications using them. Pick a naming convention that allows you to spin up new QMgrs with unique names by the hundreds or thousands, if necessary, so that you don't have to reuse QMgr names.

**Other objects**

*Use intention-revealing names*
Or to put it another way, name the object for what it *does* and not what it *is*.  For example, if you were in the habit (as many people are) of including qualifiers like `.QL` for local queues and `.QA` for aliases, then any change in topology will impact the applications using those queues.  Instead, name the queues for the functions they represent.

*Go left-to-right, most generic to most specific*
Object names, especially queues, should be constructed hierarchically beginning with the most generic qualifier and proceeding to the most specific qualifier.  For example, many shops use `APP.FUNC.SUBFUNC.VER` where `APP` is the ID of the owning application, then one or more nodes with the function and subfunction.  Many shops add a version qualifier on the end so that new versions of a service can migrate their clients on separate schedules rather than changing the service on the existing queue and making all clients change at the same time.

*The thing that reads the messages owns the queue*
If I have a service endpoint represented by a queue then there is a many-to-one relationship between the things that might call the service to the thing that provides the service.  The queue is associated with the service and the thing providing that service.  Clients are more or less anonymous.  Therefore, if any of the stakeholder applications can be said to "own" the queue, it is the service provider app that consumes messages form it.

*The thing that publishes the message owns the topic.  Sort of.*
The relationship is not as straightforward with topics.  Here it is the consumers of messages that are usually anonymous.  In that sense if the topic name reflects any application, it is most likely the publisher.  However, even publishers can be anonymous, or at least there may many of them and not all publishing at the same time.  With topics it makes much more sense that the topic tree nodes are structured for the hierarchy of data or functionality they represent.  These names tend to match the names of the publishing apps so sometimes the publisher "owns" the topic as much out of coincidence as anything else.

*Put positional qualifiers on the left*
Where names have variable numbers of qualifiers, put the positional ones on the left where scripts and automation can parse them.  Some shops where both the beginning *and* ending qualifiers are positional deal with this by using underscores for separators in the variable section of the name like `APP.FUNC.SUBFUNC1_SUBFUNC2.VER`.  Scripts and authorizations then always see a fixed number of nodes in the name but this approach can be brittle if somebody forgets and makes a name with an extra node or two.

**Further reading**
This sums up most of the general rules but some of the philosophy behind them has been captured in the Mission:Messaging column.  In particular:

- *[Embracing cultural change in the WebSphere MQ community](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0809_mismes/0809_mismes.html)*
- *[Migration, failover, and scaling in a WebSphere MQ cluster](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0811_mismes/0811_mismes.html)*
- The article *[Planning for SSL on the WebSphere MQ network](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0901_mismes/0901_mismes.html)* discusses distinguished name standards as they apply to WMQ

Comment: Thank Rob, as usual it is scholarly. I have to read it again, and will post questions, clarifications if any here. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @Shashi and @arrehman!  Let me know if there's anything important I didn't cover or if anything needs clarification. There are some topics that impact object names indirectly which I didn't try to cover here. If for example you want to know how security impacts object names, that's worth a question on its own (with about as detailed an answer) and I could link the two posts.

Comment: Any suggestion on listener names? I usually give it a name and start it in a script.

Comment: I use names like `TCP.1414` where the name includes the protocol and port.  Any reason you are not putting the listeners under QMgr control?  Then they get stopped when the QMgr comes down so there's no issues with having to clear semaphores and shared memory when the QMgr comes back up.

Comment: Say, how this VER in the names should look like? Do you have any experience in that? And is it a good practice to name the first Q or Alias with version number? Or maybe start without it and add in in another version?

Comment: Usually the version in the queue name matches the version number of the service so it is obvious to people requesting the service which queue to use.  If I'm moving from V3 to V4 of the `stripSpecialChars` service and see a queue name ending in `.V04` it should be intuitive that's the one I need. If possible, I like to start the naming with all the nodes in place.  This is because as an admin, I rely heavily on scripting to manage the QMgr and doing so makes the queue names easy to parse.